# Post method always returning 503: timeout message while using nodejs to connect to Postgre SQL db

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am running a nodejs app on Heroku and using Postgre SQL db. I am using a post method add_user to add some data to the table users. Everything works fine and data is correctly entered in the table but still I am always getting a **connection closed without response, status 503** message. May be I am not closing the connection or missing out some essentials, am new to nodejs and psql. Please help
**NodeJS add_user method:**
[image]
**CLI :** As you can see Successful Insertion message is printed, but still getting timeout message.[image]

Comment: instead of doing `res.status(200)`, change it to `res.status(200).send()` or `res.sendStatus(200)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.status(code)` sets the status code of the response but doesn't actually send anything to the client. To return a response, you either need to do `res.sendStatus(200)` or `res.status(200).send()`. For empty content, consider using `res.sendStatus(204)` which is the appropriate status code for sending empty content. It's like saying, the request is OK, but it's empty. Same method applies if you need to send other status codes: `res.status(500).send('Server error message blah blah blah')` instead of what you did with `response.send('Error ' + err)`.

Also there is a typo in your code, in the first condition `if(err)`, you do `response.send`, but in the other condition you did `res.send`. `response` is `undefined` here.